# 'Done' button not visible in the Modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to present a modal view from one of my view. The presenter view is already shown as a modal from a custom view. My problem is that I am not able to see the 'Done' button on the new Modal view presented. Below is my code. Am I missing something?

```
    UIViewController *aViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aViewController] autorelease];
    [aNavigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissMe)];
    [aNavigationController.navigationItem  setLeftBarButtonItem:aBarButtonItem];
    MyView *aView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [aViewController.view addSubview:aView];
    [self presentModalViewController:aNavigationController animated:YES];
    [aViewController release];

- (void)dismissMe {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: I dont think stacking up view controllers like this is good design... But the answer to your question lies in the navigationController.view.frame. Try setting it explicitly... and if possible, add a pic to the question.

Comment: I did that by setting the frame to CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) but it does not help.

Comment: Please add a pic. May be aView covers up the screen. What about that frame size ?

Comment: Added the image. Please take a look at the Q itself.

Comment: what happens if you set it to (0, 44, 320, 416)?  (my only guess is that your aView is covering up the navbar view)

Comment: Same results. I don't think view is overlapping the nav bar.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand weel the question, you can try a solution like this:
Write this in the `viewDidLoad` or `init` method of the modal view controller you want to show from the actual view:

```
UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self selector:@selector(dismissMe)];
self.navigationController.leftBarButtonItem = done;
```

and implement you `dismissMe` method.
Instead, in the presenter controller write this where you want to present the new modal controller:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controllerYouWantToShow];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Obviusly, `controllerYouWantToShow` is a pointer/variable pointing your view controller you want to show... I usually do this to solve a problem like yours... However, check the code because I havent't tested it :)
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks - this helped me.  I was trying to show a controller that extend UINavigationController instead of simply wrapping the call inside a generic nav controller using initWithRootViewController...now the done button is showing!